# Some stored procedures are not displayed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a wired issue with some of the `stored procedures` on my database. Those are not displayed in object explorer. I tried using filter to search by name and still it not appears!!!

Thing is when I try to create those missing ones it says the stored procedure is already exists. And I tried altering the SP and it worked. But I cannot see those yet.

Any idea regarding this?

Comment: @MartinSmith: I refreshed/restarted `sql-sqrver` before asking question here !!!

Comment: Down voter please explain the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this conundrum before and it was because I was actually trying to create the stored procedure in the **master** database. I believe by default, in SSMS, this database is selected by default.

If you are using SSMS, ensure that the database selected from the dropdown list (usually top left on the query window toolbar) is the correct database.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a number of things, including but not limited to:

- Is there another object, not a stored procedure, present with that name?
- Is the procedure in an unanticipated schema? In SSMS, they are listed in schema-then-procedure name order
- Do you have sufficient access rights to see the procedure? (Probably, but it has to be mentioned)
- Has it been marked as an MS-shipped procedure? Those may not appear with user schemas
- Another "probably not", are you sure you are looking at the right database?

Comment: 1. No 2.No 3. Yes 4. No 5.Yes

Comment: At which point, I'd need hands-on access to figure what was gonig on. Sorry.

Comment: I have restarted the pc and it was sorted!! not exactly sure what happned.